# What is best option for BI capabilities with SharePoint

Tags: reporting-services, excel-services, reports, bi

In SP2010 there are silver light dashboards used to be there in our project. Now we planned to convert them into BI reports in SP2013. All these report data is coming from list and libraries. Some reports should also have drill down capabilities. I am planned with performance point services or excel services. But is it proper one. Reports should have filter capability. If I install SSRS for SharePoint is it possible to achieve the same? Everywhere showing examples of external database like Adventure Works with sharepoint. But I have to build a report using list and libraries. Which will be best option?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding **If I install SSRS for SharePoint is it possible to achieve the same? Everywhere showing examples of external database like Adventure Works with SharePoint. But I have to build a report using list and libraries**

Yes , you can use SSRS to show data from SharePoint Lists using Report Builder ,  to do that check the detail steps at 
[Create SSRS Report from SharePoint 2013 List using Report Builder 3.0](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/12/create-ssrs-report-from-sharepoint-list.html#ixzz4LCoNvADk)

Regarding **What's the best option ?**

you have mentioned most of the available BI and reporting tools in SharePoint, I suggest When you try to select appropriate tools you should be aware of the following 5 factors

- The SharePoint Edition.
- SharePoint Topology.
- The Capability of the tools.
- The Client Requirement.
- your knowledge with this tool.

Based on the above factors you can select your appropriate tools. (**Note :** Based on your mentioned scenario , I suggest SSRS)

**Below is simple comparison between SSRS , PerformancePoint and Excel Services **

**The SharePoint Edition**

- PerformancePoint. (Require SharePoint Enterprise)
- SSRS. (Require SharePoint Enterprise/Standard/Foundation)
- Excel Services. (Require SharePoint Enterprise)

**SQL Services Reporting Services - SSRS**

*Pros*

- Flexibility in defining specific formatting and layout, specific item -placement, multiple or composite report items, groups, headers, footers, subtotals
- Report caching and snapshot for better performance especially if the source data query is complex and takes longer to execute
- Creating report subscription for automatic report delivery via email or file share mode
- Can combine multiple data sources (relational and OLAP data) into a single report
- Additional charting options - map, area, range, scatter, polar, 3D, sparklines, data bars, etc
- As similar as PPS dashboard, SSRS reports can also be deployed on a SharePoint site for collaboration

*Cons*

- Harder to create dashboards and therefore often done by IT people
- No automatic drill-through and drill-across features

**PerformancePoint Services - PPS**

*Pros*

- Unique decomposition tree features for better and multi-level data analysis; you can refer to this tip for more on decomposition tree feature.
- Automatic drill-through and drill-across features using the decomposition tree on SSAS cube
- Stunning/great appearance of dashboard, score cards, etc.
- Scorecards allow users to enter comments against KPI values
- Usually, less development time required in comparison with SSRS reports or dashboard

*Cons*

- Comes with SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Edition
- Limited flexibility in defining formatting and layout; cannot be customized or modified as much as SSRS

**Excel Services**

is a remarkably good choice for a Self Service BI scenarios. The ease of development and the flexibility of the UI options are great.  The greatest drawback is inability to interact with charts and graphs on the Excel Services rendered web page.  Also, if you are trying to delight the end-user with you data visualization, it can be a challenge as the final product at the end still looks very much like Excel

Form more details check

- [comparing-performancepoint-powerview-excel-services-and-reporting-services](https://businessintelligist.com/2012/04/02/comparing-performancepoint-powerview-excel-services-and-reporting-services/)
- [sql-server-reporting-services-vs-performancepoint-services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2737/sql-server-reporting-services-vs-performancepoint-services/)

Comment: Excel Services does have interactions with slicers and powerpivot, which can be used effectively. Have you considered PowerView? I haven't used it recently, but it was looking very good and moving to HTML5. The other possibility is PowerBI, although not available directly in SharePoint at the moment.

Comment: @M.Qassas, thanks for your details steps. I am having SharePoint 2013 enterprise. If use excel services, I can get data from list? Graphs has to be updated automatically when data was changed in the list.

Comment: @Mihir so sorry for late answer I was not here, , yes you can do this , please check http://tavislovell.com/create-a-dashboard-from-your-sharepoint-list-data-using-excel-services-and-the-excel-web-access-web-part/  and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2015/07/28/excel-services-consuming-a-sharepoint-list-using-the-listdata-svc/ and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2013/07/11/excel-services-using-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source/ please tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: @Mihir Please Don't forget to **Mark** and **Upvote** the correct answer in case it helped you